# Reciprocity (Ehrhart-style) for real polytopes?

Tags: convex-polytopes, combinatorial-geometry

Is there some sense in which the well-known Ehrhart reciprocity law for rational, convex, polytopes can be extended to any convex polytope with arbitrary real vertices?

In other words, given any real closed (and convex) polytope $P$, is the function that enumerates integer points in dilates of $P$ somehow simply related to the function that enumerates integer points in the dilates of the interior of $P$?

Here's one possible direction, given that we no longer have the usual quasi-polynomial behavior for the integer point enumerator.  Does there exist some piecewise smooth function $L(t)$, of a real variable $t$, which satisfies the following properties:

(1) $L(t)$ agrees with the integer point enumerator  #{${\mathbb Z}^d \cap tP$} at all positive integer values of $t$.

(2) $L(-t)$ counts the integer points in the interior of $tP$, for all positive integers $t$.

(3) The Fourier transform of $L$ is supported at a countable set of points.

Intuitively, for all real and positive $t$, such a smooth function $L(t)$ would approximate the piecewise constant function #{${\mathbb Z}^d \cap tP$}). Property (3) above was suggested by Allen Knutson.

(ADDED) Let's try to see what happens in dimension one.  So we let $P := [0, \alpha]$, a one-dimensional polytope, with $\alpha$ a positive irrational number. We let $L_P(n)$ be the number of integer points in the dilation $nP$, so that here 
$L_P(n) =  [n\alpha]+1$.  For the interior $P^o$, we have $L_{P^o}(n) = [n\alpha]$.  Using 
{x} $= \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z - \{0\}} \frac{1}{k}e^{2\pi i k x}$, and
$L_P(n)= n\alpha -$  {$n\alpha$}+1,
we have:
$$
L_P(n)  = [n\alpha]+1 = n\alpha + \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z - \{0\} } 
\frac{1}{k}e^{2\pi i k n  \alpha},
$$
and let's use this last expression as the extension of $L_P(n)$ to all real values of $n$.  We now check for reciprocity, using this new definition of our extended function $L_P(n)$:
$$
L_P(-n) 
= -n\alpha + \frac{1}{2} - \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z - \{0\} } \frac{1}{k}e^{-2\pi i k n  \alpha}
$$
$$
= -n\alpha + \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z - \{0\} } \frac{1}{k}e^{2\pi i k n  \alpha} \  \ (\text{replacing } k \in \mathbb Z \  by \  -k \in \mathbb Z)
$$
$$
 = - [ n\alpha]= - L_{P^o}(n),
$$
which is a reciprocity law.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Say we have two functions $h(n),h^\circ(n)$ enumerating points in $nP,nP^\circ$. Then in the case of integer vertices, we can say "these are polynomials! so it makes sense to plug in negative values" and observe that $h^\circ(n) = (-1)^n h(n)$. But for a general $P$, how do you extend to negative argument?

Comment: Does it help at all that $h_P(n) - h^\circ_P(n) = \sum_F h^\circ_F(n) = \sum_F (-1)^{\codim F} h_F(n)$, where the sums are over proper faces of $P$?

Comment: @Allen: We might be able to first extend the function $h_P(n)$ to some real analytic function of $n$ and then extend $n$ to the whole real line, and finally try to 'plug in' a real value different from $-1$, for example.  

The Brianchon-Gram identity you mention might help. For example, one possible thing to try is to introduce a "damping factor", such as $e^{-\langle n, s \rangle}$, in front of each $h_P(n)$ and then sum over all $n \in \mathbb Z^d$ to get a generating function that we can work with. 
 

Comment: @Allen:  Thanks for your comment - I've edited my question to focus it in one possible direction.

Comment: You'll need some additional constraint on your interpolating function, since any values at the integers can be interpolated by an entire function.  

Comment: I think there should be some Fourier transform statement, in terms of distributions on circles. Polynomial $\iff$ supported at the identity, quasipolynomial $\iff$ supported at some finite set of elements of finite order. Maybe given $h(>0)$ there's a unique extension to ${\mathbb Z}$ such that the Fourier transform is supported on a finite set? Or is a countable sum that converges especially quickly?

Comment: @Andreas: right you are, thanks. Offhand, its not completely clear what the extra constraint should be, perhaps Allen's suggestion regarding the Fourier transform will help, though. 

Comment: @Allen: this is quite interesting - can you add a little more detail to the statement that $\hat h_P$ is supported at a finite set? 

Comment: Let $\hat f$ be the delta function on the circle supported at $2\pi x \in [0,2\pi)$. I think the Fourier transform is $f(n) = \exp(nx)$, so, periodic  iff $x$ is rational. More to the point, if $x$ is rational then $f$ is quasipolynomial. Apply derivatives and such to $\hat f$ to get more complicated distributions at $2\pi x$; meanwhile $f$ becomes $\exp(nx) p(n)$. Now take finite linear combinations, and you exactly get quasipolynomials. 

Comment: (I meant $\exp(inx)$, of course)

Comment: @Allen: thanks, I see what you mean and edited my question now to include your suggestion, which is a very naturally motivated one.